# How do I properly open an image from a folder to process it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to open images and edit them. But when opened, "no such file or directory" or "<ImagingCore object at 0x0000020625552F70>" comes out. The path is specified correctly, checked several times. How do I open the image correctly?
Also how can I save an already edited image to another folder with the same name?
'''

```
    from PIL import Image
    import os
    def convertImage():
        folder_dir = "C:\проект\Images"
        for images in os.listdir(folder_dir):
        img = Image.open(images)
        img = img.convert("RGBA")
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

'No such file or directory' is caused by the path. It has backslashes, which is an escape character. So the correct way to define your path is:

```
folder_dir = "C:\\project\\Images"
```

To save the edited image you can use:

```
img.save('path/to/output/img')
```

Comment: Outputs the following error "No such file or directory: '111583.jpg'"

Comment: Image.open(folder_dir + '\\' + images), since the listdir only provides the file names, not the path.

Comment: In this case, the image is represented as "<ImagingCore object at 0x000001ECFFFA2F70>"

Comment: Yes, it is an Image instance. If you print it, then the output will be its memory address (0x000001ECFFFA2F70). If you want to display it: img.show()

Comment: But the image is now not editable

Comment: How come? How do you want to edit it?

Comment: I need to trim it

Comment: There is a crop() method: img.crop((x1, y1, x2, y2)).

Comment: Also further in the code I represent the image as an array of pixels, but it is not represented

Comment: What do you mean it is not represented? Can you show the code?

Comment: ws = img.size[0]
    he = img.size[1]
    fon = Image.new('RGBA', (he, he), 'white')
    fon.paste(img, (((he-ws)//2), 0), img)
    k = 0
    l = 0
    temp = []
    datas = fon.getdata()
    newData = []

Comment: ws = img.size[0]
        he = img.size[1]
        fon = Image.new('RGBA', (he, he), 'white')
        fon.paste(img, (((he-ws)//2), 0), img)
        k = 0
        l = 0
        temp = []
        datas = fon.getdata()
        newData = []

Comment: The paste() method expects the parameters in the following order: im1, im2, box. You misplaced the parameters.